# Usando compomente TDBComboBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, combobox

Estou com o seguinte problema, quando seleciono um item no TDBComboBox ao sair do componente ele seleciona automaticamente o ultimo registro.

```
DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumos.Close;
DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumos.Open;
DBComboFornecedor.Items.Clear;
DBComboFornecedor.Items.Add('Selecione');
while DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumos.Eof = False do
begin
  DBComboFornecedor.Items.Add(DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumosCodFornecedor.Text);
  DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumos.Next;
end;
```

No compomente TDBComboBox:

```
Style -> csDropDownList
DataSource -> Ds_ConsForncedores
DataFiel -> CodFornecedor
```

No DataSource

```
DataSet -> DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumos
```

Comment: O problema é que você deve ter colocado no evento OnChange/OnExit do componente, com isso cada vez que você seleciona um ele ativa o evento e para no último, faz a busca uma vez só e então vai dar certo.

Comment: @JeffersonRudolf coloquei esse código no OnActive do form, nos eventos OnChange/OnExit não tenho nenhum código.

Comment: O problema não acontece ao vc selecionar acontece que quando esta adicionando um item no combobox vc esta percorrendo a Query com o Next e com isso fica posicionado na ultima posição, para pegar o seleciona vc tem que criar algo no evento OnClosepopup do combo e posicionar a Query de acordo com o escolhido no combobox. Coloca ao terminar de adicionar o First na Query;

Comment: Uma vez que no DBCOmbobox esta vinculado ao Datasource nao precisa adicionar os itens manualmente, o proprio delphi faz isso para voce. Talvez o ato de adicionar esta causando o erro. O delphi consegue controlar perfeitamente os componentes de DataControl pra o programador ganhar praticidade e agilidade na programação;

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite Tiago
Pelo código que você postou o problema de o combobox aparecer o último registro é porque você fez um while not eof.
Então quando chega ao final no while é o ultimo regitro que fica na combo.
Se você quer que o primeiro ADD que você fez (SELECIONE) apareça basta você colocar apôs o "end" do while DBComboFornecedor.itemindex:=0;

```
while DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumos.Eof = False do
begin
  DBComboFornecedor.Items.Add(DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumosCodFornecedor.Text);
  DM_BancoInsumos.IBQCons_ForneInsumos.Next;
end;

DBComboFornecedor.itemindex:=0;
```

Espero ter compreendido o seu problema :)

Comment: Eu faço isso Ricardo, o "Selecione" aparece setado no TDBComboBox, a questão vem quando eu seleciono um valor do TDBComboBox, ao sair do compomente ele perde esse valor indo automaticamente para o último valor do TDBComboBox.

Comment: Boa tarde @Tiago Casanova.  Em que evento esta esse código que você postou?? Tipo no ONEXIT do DBCombobox, no ONCREATE do form etc..

Comment: Está no evento OnActive do Form @Ricardo M. Souza

Comment: @Tiago Casanova Cara.. se tu quiser me enviar o formulário com o script da tabela eu posso dar uma olhada aqui.

Comment: @tiago Casanova Uma curiosidade. Se o datasource esta ligado na query e o dblookyp esta ligado no datasource e campo você NÃO precisa adicionar os campos no lookup eles irão automaticamente.